# SSIS handling semi structured data source

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis, vba

Other than using a script task, are there any ways of handling/parsing a semi structured excel data source in SSIS?

Comment: None that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Data Flow Flow Task to work with Excel data source.

Drag a Data Flow Task into the Control Flow pane. Right click the Data Flow Task and select Edit.

From there, you can drag a "Source Assistant" into the Data Flow Pane. Inside the Source Assistant you are able to select Excel as the Source Type. Then you select the File Path to the Excel file.

Then, you can connect the Source Assistant to a Destination Assistant, Transformation, or whatever you need in order to do what you need to do with the data.